# What does declare -A do in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm confused by what `declare -A` does here, could somebody explain?

```
declare -A deploy
roles="test1 test2 test3 test4"

for role in $roles; do
    deploy[$role]=${!role}
done
```

More confuse about `${!role}`

Comment: What did the man page say about it?

Comment: There are several shells in use under Linux. Are you asking about `bash`? If so, please add a `bash` tag to your question.

Comment: try `help declare` for docs

Comment: `${!role}` is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html); look for "indirection". (If you add a new question after an answer has been posted, it's likely to be missed.)

Comment: ...potentially even *intentionally* missed and/or rolled back -- editing a question in a way that makes existing answers incomplete or invalid is not kosher behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`declare -A` defines an associative array, one that can map a string to another string.

For example:

```
pax> declare -A mymap

pax> mymap[washington]=george
pax> mymap[lincoln]=abe

pax> echo ${!mymap[*]}
washington lincoln

pax> echo ${mymap[no_such_key]}

pax> echo ${mymap[washington]}
george

pax> echo ${mymap[lincoln]}
abe
```

---

In terms of the `${!role}` bit, this is indirect expansion. Normally, a variable will have one level of expansion as you can see below:

```
pax> plugh=xyzzy
pax> xyzzy=zorkmid
pax> echo ${plugh}
xyzzy
```

However, you can also treat the expansion of the name as another *variable* which is subsequently expanded:

```
pax> echo ${!plugh}
zorkmid
```

What happens there is that the `plugh` is expanded to `xyzzy`, then that itself is expanded again to `zorkmid`.

In your *specific* case where, for example, the variable `role` is set to `test1`, the following lines are equivalent:

```
deploy[$role]=${!role}
deploy[test1]=${test1}
```

Answer (score 4):

`declare -A deploy` marks `deploy` as the name of an associative array, one that maps one string to another.

Each time through the loop, a different word from the expansion of `$roles` is added as a new key to the array. `${!role}` is indirect parameter expansion, expanding to the value of the variable whose name is the value of `$role`. The loop is equivalent to

```
deploy[test1]=$test1
deploy[test2]=$test2
deploy[test3]=$test3
deploy[test4]=$test4
```

Comment: can you please explain this: ${!role} is indirect parameter expansion, expanding to the value of the variable whose name is the value of $role

Comment: @ArbabNazar, see [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for a detailed discussion of indirect expansions. That said, the sentence you quoted is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? If `role=foo`, and `foo=bar`, then the variable whose name is the value of `$role` is `foo`, and the value of that variable (which is to say, the variable whose name is `foo`) is `bar`.